# Inserir números aleatórios através de procedure

Tags: sql-insert, stored-procedures, oracle12c

Estou tentando inserir alguns registro aleatórios em uma tabela, porém estou encontrando alguns erros.

criei uma tabela para testar;
`create table teste_p(handle int, nome varchar(20));

preciso que seja inserido algo do tipo:

create or replace procedure socpro.insere_teste(

i number;

begin  for i in 1 .. 10 loop

insert into socpro.teste_p(handle,nome) values (aqui numeros aleatorios usando o dbms.random.value,   aqui string aleatoria usando dbms.random.string)

end loop;

commit;

end;)

Answer (score 0):

```
--sequencia artificial
SELECT LEVEL 
FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;

--COM ALEATORIOS
SELECT LEVEL handle ,DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('U',20) nome  
FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;

--COM INSERT
INSERT INTO teste_p
 SELECT LEVEL handle ,DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('U',20) nome  
 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
```

[doc](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_random.htm#ARPLS67506)